# How can I get a cryptographically secure version of this hashing?

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, sha, intuit-wasabi

I'm trying to write a new method for the [code in Wasabi A/B's](https://github.com/intuit/wasabi) LoginToken.java class. The class defines an class of type LoginToken and implements a hashCode() method.  As of now, the method reads:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

However, I understand that HashCodeBuilder is not that secure, [from the Apache Commons description](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html). The file itself imports `import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;`. Ideally, I want to do SHA256; I got the idea [here](https://www.baeldung.com/sha-256-hashing-java) What should I change to achieve this?

Comment: There is no way for a hash function with an output of 32 bits to be secure in all the normal ways that cryptographic secure hash functions are. The usual security requirement for function like Java's `hashCode` is that they be resistant to hash flooding denial of service attacks when used to build data structures for lookups.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk how can I at least make this closest to "cryptographically secure" as possible?

Comment: Step 1: Figure out what you want to use the hash for. Step 2: Pick the already developed correct hash suggested by the answer to step 1.

Answer (score 3):

Hashcode in Java is used for different purposes than a SHA256 hashcode would be used for. Hashcode in Java is for use in collections. A SHA256 hashcode would be used for authentication of data. Yes, the two are both hashes, but they are not the same.

... plus there is no way to implement a SHA1 hashcode from the hashcode method in java.lang.Object, as this method is defined to return an int, and a SHA1 hashcode is going to be much bigger

Comment: Trimming is the easier way.

Comment: @kelalaka once you trim though, your hashcode is no longer going to be cryptographically secure

Comment: That is depending on [the requirement](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64314/18298). How much collision resistance you want? How much pre-image and 2. pre-image you want. that is all must be answered. Remember SHA-224 is truncated SHA-256 with different initial values.

Comment: @kelalaka but then what's the point of calculating a SHA-256? It would create a lot of unnecessary processing just to return a much simpler hashcode. In fact this extra processing could very well make it more costly than hash collision

Comment: @kelalaka we simply want the most secure and easy to implement substitute to this function we can get.

Comment: @JerryAtric security has nothing to do with java.lang.Object.hashcode() making this method more *secure* achieves nothing

Comment: @ControlAltDel but this is not java.lang.Object.hashCode(), this is Apache's hashCodeBuilder, an instance of which is returned in the hashCode() implementation in question